# Was this a legitimate question? Could I have asked it differently?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I asked this a second ago and was a little aggrieved to have a bunch of people jump on an question it's validity.

[C#. Fastest Regex to match any string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5147298/c-fastest-regex-to-match-any-string)

I know there are a million other ways I could do it but surely even academic questions have value. Are there any tips for how I could have framed the question differently to avoid the snarky remarks and the bad karma from down votes?

Answer (score 8):

You were veering away from the instruction

> You should only ask **practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face**.

from [the FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq), but you didn't ask any of the explicitly barred questions:

> - every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite `______`?”
> - your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers: “I use `______` for `______`, what do you use?”
> - there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”
> - we are being asked an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if `______` happened?”
> - it is a rant disguised as a question: “`______` sucks, am I right?”

I think your wording just made it seem a little bit like a subjective joke question. You only got a single downvote and your question has not been closed. Maybe you could provide some insight as to what led to you asking the question?

Comment: This is a good answer. It's good to provide background when asking questions that will pique people's curiosity as to why you would be doing something that most would consider odd.

Comment: "there is no actual problem to be solved" sounds like a winner; why would you actually need this?